# What is Bluetooth file received location

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer

I have two applications. One will transfer a set of files and another will receive via blue-tooth. This transfer is successful. I can see files via file explorer. 
Now, I want to read them through my app. 
I have seen received location changes according to your device. Its not always download\ blue-tooth. 
So,

- How do I know path of received file?
- Can I change default path for a particular sender application or as a whole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to manage Bluetooth connections yourself. Follow the guidelines given in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

As far as changing the path of default Bluetooth applications is not easy. Some OEM's may expose this, others might not. So best way to make your application to work on all devices is get your own stream of bytes and write it to your location.

Comment: Thank a lot for your time and answer Royston. I am transferring files thro' Intent. Now, I will need to work with bluetoothSocket. ryt? Can i send with Intent and work BT Socket only on receiving side?

Comment: will obex be good for my application or will it be overhead? please suggest i cant figure out.

Comment: Not much idea on that.